# React Axios get method is not displaying any data even though console.log output shows data

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am getting data in console but not able to display on browser. Please let me know where i am wrong. Console data also send blank array.
My code is following
------------------------------------------------------[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSnry.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import './orderform.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Card } from 'antd';
import { Button } from 'antd';
class Orderform1 extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      itemgroups:[]
     };
  }
componentDidMount() {
     axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/itemgroup/get-itemgroup')
        .then(res => {

          this.setState({ itemgroups: res.data}

            );}

               )

        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
           }

    render() { 
      // console.log(this.state.itemgroups);
      const {itemgroups} =  this.state;

      console.log(itemgroups);
        return (
           <div>
           <ul>
            {
            itemgroups.length > 0  &&           
            itemgroups.map(itemgroup =>
             <li key={itemgroup.item_group_id}>{itemgroup.item_group_name}</li>
            )}

          </ul>
          </div>
     );}
}

export default Orderform1;
```

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like `itemgroups` might be one level deeper. When you set state, try `this.setState({ itemgroups: res.data.itemgroups})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot, it looks like `itemgroups` might be one level deeper. When you set state, try `this.setState({ itemgroups: res.data.itemgroup })`

Comment: Thanks Nick. Issue has been resolved as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

res.data contains an object that contains the array you are trying to map